# Calculate field has_impact based on start and end time

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to populate field *has_impact* based on the following for each feed view in the session.

`has_impact` is true when difference between `(view_end_time - view_start_time) > 3` and `view_perc > 0.8` else false.

*view_logs* table

```
create table view_logs(session_id varchar(10), post_id int, 
                         ts int, event_name varchar(50), view_perc float);
    
insert into view_logs(session_id, post_id, ts, event_name, view_perc)
    values
    ('m1', 1000, 1524600, 'view_start', null),
    ('m1', 1000, 1524602, 'view_end', 0.85),
    ('m1', 1000, 1524650, 'view_start', null),
    ('m1', 1000, 1524654, 'view_end', 0.9),
    ('m1', 2000, 1524700, 'view_start', null),
    ('m1', 2000, 1524707, 'view_end', 0.3),
    ('m1', 2000, 1524710, 'view_start', null),
    ('m1', 2000, 1524713, 'view_end', 0.9);
```

I have tried **[this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/U47fgSD19rVLBsEnmcRQg/1)** but not getting desired output. can anyone help me to identify what I am doing wrong?

query:

```
with cte as
  (  
    select
      pv1.session_id,
      pv1.post_id,
      pv2.view_perc,
      pv1.ts as start_time,
      min(pv2.ts) as end_time
    from view_logs pv1
    join view_logs pv2
    on pv1.session_id = pv2.session_id
    and pv1.post_id = pv2.post_id
    and pv1.event_name <> pv2.event_name
    and pv1.ts < pv2.ts
    group by
      pv1.session_id,
      pv1.post_id,
      pv2.view_perc,
      pv1.ts
 )  
 
select
    session_id,
    post_id,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    case
        when (end_time - start_time > 3  and view_perc > 0.8 )then 'yes'
        else 'no'
    end as has_meaningful_view
from cte
```

desired output:

```
*--------------------------------------------------------*
|session_id| post_id | start_time | end_time | has_impact|
*--------------------------------------------------------*
|  m1      | 1000    | 1524600    | 1524602  | no        |
|  m1      | 1000    | 1524650    | 1524654  | yes       |
|  m1      | 2000    | 1524700    | 1524707  | no        |
|  m1      | 2000    | 1524710    | 1524713  | no        |
*--------------------------------------------------------*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each record with **view_start** and the record after it with **view_end** may be joined using self join, and since you don't have an incremented column, we can construct one using `row_number()` to be used as a condition for the join clause:

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over( partition by session_id, post_id order by ts) as rn
  from view_logs
)
select c1.session_id, c1.post_id,
         c1.ts as start_time, c2.ts as end_time,
         case when c2.view_perc > 0.8 and c2.ts - c1.ts > 3
              then 'Yes' else 'No' end as has_impact
from cte c1
inner join cte c2 on c1.event_name = 'view_start' 
                  and c2.event_name = 'view_end'
                  and c1.session_id = c2.session_id
                  and c1.post_id = c2.post_id
                  and c2.rn = c1.rn + 1
order by c1.session_id, c1.post_id, c1.ts
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1INwPQoO)

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that each start time has an end time, you can aggregate using row_number function as the following:

```
select session_id, post_id,
       max(case when event_name='view_start' then ts end) startTime,
       max(case when event_name='view_end' then ts end) endTime,
       case 
         when 
          max(case when event_name='view_end' then ts end)
        - max(case when event_name='view_start' then ts end) > 3 
          and max(view_perc) > 0.8
         then 'yes' else 'no'
       end as hasimpact
from
(
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by session_id, post_id order by ts) rn
  from view_logs
) t
group by session_id, post_id, (rn-1)/ 2
order by session_id, post_id, min(ts)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vfxGz6TA)

Answer (score 1):

this might not get you exactly what you want but it does calculate the `has_impact` column

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN event_name = 'view_start'
                THEN ts
            END AS start_time
        ,CASE 
            WHEN event_name = 'view_end'
                THEN ts
            END AS end_time
    FROM view_logs
    )
SELECT session_id
    ,post_id
    ,start_time
    ,end_time
    ,CASE 
        WHEN end_time - lag(start_time, 1) OVER (
                ORDER BY (
                        SELECT NULL
                        )
                ) > 3
            AND view_perc > 0.8
            THEN true
        ELSE false
        END AS has_impact
FROM cte;
```

output:

| session_id | post_id | start_time | end_time | has_impact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m1 | 1000 | 1524600 | null | false |
| m1 | 1000 | null | 1524602 | false |
| m1 | 1000 | 1524650 | null | false |
| m1 | 1000 | null | 1524654 | true |
| m1 | 2000 | 1524700 | null | false |
| m1 | 2000 | null | 1524707 | false |
| m1 | 2000 | 1524710 | null | false |
| m1 | 2000 | null | 1524713 | false |

Comment: thank you but is it possible to do without lag? FYI: Demo link directs me to the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** that every end has a start immediately preceding it, you can simply use the [window function `lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) once in a subquery:

```sql
SELECT session_id, post_id, start_time, ts AS end_time, view_perc
     , (ts - start_time) > 3 AND view_perc > 0.8 AS has_impact
FROM  (
   SELECT *, lag(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id, post_id ORDER BY ts) AS start_time
   FROM   view_logs
   ) sub
WHERE  event_name = 'view_end'
ORDER  BY session_id, post_id, start_time;  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TVsCMTlS)

Should be fastest as it only needs a single pass over the table.

If my assumption does not hold, declare what we can assume *exactly*.